# Jz BT201 mics for nature recording

Tags: microphone, nature-recording, field-recording

Hi Guys
I've been researching some good mics for nature recording, since i can't
afford the obvious sennheiser MKH line right now, and i came across with these

http://www.jzmic.com/en/products/28

The specs seem seriously impressive for the price (800euros for a pair)
with 3 different capsules

Has anybody had a chance to hear these?

Thanks, and sorry if i'm beating the "which microphone" horse

Answer (score 1):

I don't know man. I'm always interested in new mic companys and their models, but I get skeptical when they don't list qualifying data on the specs.

What's the deviation in frequency response? What is the reference level for the sensitivity rating? [Usually it's 1V at 1Pa, but that's a dangerous assumption if it's not listed.] Those are the kinds of omissions that make me worry. I'd definitely look for some reviews first.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun! The frequency response is ruler flat up to 20kHz according to their chart, and the sensitivity rating is listed as 11mV/Pa
And their noise A weighted is l12dBA which is odd, in the mic shoots i've heard at gearslutz the examples were noisiers than other microphones with a listed self noise of 16dBa, but maybe those shootouts weren't made properly (and then again, its gearslutz)

Comment: @Filipe - yeah, nothing is ever ruler flat. there's always +/- at least 2dB. i saw the sensitivity level, but there was no reference to give you scale. most manufacturers will list that "1V at 1Pa" that i mentioned as a reference so you can get a clearer picture. i always assume that data is being hidden if that extra info isn't there...it's to easy too fudge numbers without it. might account for the noisier results you heard.

Answer (score 1):

One serious issue to consider is that you'll definitely need wind protection for Nature Recording. Looking at the shape of those mics I don't know if you'll be able to fit a ball gag and fur cover on those.

For those who can't afford Sennehisers, usually the Audio Technica AT4021/22 (cards/omnis) are recommended. I have a pair of the AT4021's I use for nature/ambient recording and I'm very satisfied.

There is also an older version of the ATs named 3031/32 that you can sometimes find deals on. The specs are more or less the same.

Check the Nature Sound Recordists list for exhaustive discussion on microphones:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/naturerecordists/

Answer (score 1):

I have the BT 201 3/s and I'm very satisfied, the best thing is that the sound is very clear and doesn't need EQ. Well I'm using mostly on drums and perucssions so don't know how they would act in field recording. Here's a review about them http://recordinghacks.com/2011/01/13/jz-dmk1-review/